# ember-data enforces model schema

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, ember.js, ember-data

I'm just digging into Ember JS for the first time, and I'm playing around with ember-data to fetch JSON from an API. As far as I can see, I have to define the schema of the JSON in my model if I want to access these attributes at a view/template level.

I am familiar with Backbone JS and there we only had to define the relationships between models, not the schema *and* the relationships like Ember.

Is there any way to circumvent this, or any ember-data alternatives that don't enforce the use of a schema? Our data model is rather large and having to define each attribute is laborious and seems somewhat unnecessary. I would prefer to only have to define the relationship between models.

I have used the following code to deduce this assertion so please correct me if I'm wrong.

**Works**

app.js

```
App.Service = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string')
});
```

index.html

```
{{#each service in model}}
  <li>{{service.title}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

**Doesn't work**

app.js

```
App.Service = DS.Model.extend();
```

index.html

```
{{#each service in model}}
  <li>{{service.title}}</li>
{{/each}}
```